# Array no .ini Como fazer?

Tags: php, ini

Olá pessoal eu gostaria de saber se à possibilidade de fazer array no .ini

Utilizando o php para chamar a mesma ?

Comment: Eu ia responder a sua pergunta, mas acho melhor você ler isto primeiro amigo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4067/3635

Comment: essa é nova, o pessoal metendo o ferro e eu nem sabendo de nada !

Comment: Edward eu mandei várias mensagens pra você e você ignorou todas, não leve a mal a postagem, mas você está ignorando o uso correto do site. Eu te orientei várias vezes e você não me respondeu e nem passou a usar corretamente o site, só depois disto que eu abri aquele postagem no META e eu mandei 3 vezes o link pra você. Você não leu porque não quis, me perdoe a sinceridade. Por favor se atente ao bom uso do site de agora em diante e se tiver alguma duvida de como usar pode me perguntar. Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: eu lamento mesmo pelo ocorrido eu só entro para perguntar, mas eu irei começar a organizar ok #guilherme, eu irei ver a respeito disso, compreender eu compreendi mais né, poderia ter me enviado o link para eu acompanhar !

Comment: @EdwardJunior Como assim poderia ter te enviado o link? Eu te enviei 3 vezes. Até o Vitor te enviou o link, veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45151/como-esconder-iframe-quando-entrar-no-site#comment148630_45157 (isto foi no dia 14/02)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Use a função [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) para carregar o arquivo INI e retorna as configurações contidas nele em um array associativo.

---

<sub>**ini.ini**</sub>

```
a = A
b = B
c = C

args[] = A
args[] = B
args[] = C
```

<sub>**php**</sub>

```
print_r( parse_ini_file( 'ini.ini' ) );
```

<sub>**Output**</sub>

```
Array
(
    [a] => A
    [b] => B
    [c] => C
    [args] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
            [2] => C
        )

)
```